# unable to deploy ingress in local kubernetes cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to setup frontend for my two web applications by using ingress controller in local kubernetes cluster. I followed all steps outlined in [1] and detailed instructions in [2]. But so far out of luck. The error I got is the following:

```
Warning CreatingLoadBalancerFailed Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load balancer for service default/frontend: error creating loadbalancer a58617b3f260011e8ad84fa163e0c90a: error creating loadbalancer {a58617b3f260011e8ad84fa163e0c90a
Kubernetes external service a58617b3f260011e8ad84fa163e0c90a 7b4db6f7-3fc1-4c07-a84d-5c15b46e3ac2 <nil> }: Expected HTTP response code [201 202] when accessing [POST https://host.xyz.com:9696/v2.0/lbaas/loadbalancers],
but got 409 instead
{"NeutronError": {"message": "Quota exceeded for resources: ['loadbalancer'].", "type": "OverQuota", "detail": ""}}
```

and my service stays in a pending state.

So far I have no idea where to look at to identify the problem and would appreciate any advice.

The manifest yaml file is almost identical to [2], it only lists https interface. But here it is for completeness

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
   name: frontend
   annotations:
     ingress.kub.webernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: ing-secret
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
  containers:
  - args:
    - /nginx-ingress-controller
    - "--default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend"
    - "--default-ssl-certificate=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ing-secret"
  env:
    - name: POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    - name: POD_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
  image: "gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.5"
  rules:
  - host: host.xxx.com
    https:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 8881
      - path: /app2
        backend:
          serviceName: app2
          servicePort: 8882
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
```

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

[2] https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-nginx-ingress-on-kubernetes-2b733d8d2f45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like OpenStack lbaas is being used by kubernetes to provision the load balancer service underlying the ingress resource (see `https://host.xyz.com:9696/v2.0/lbaas/loadbalancers` in the error log)

AFAIK this error indicates a resource limit has been reached on the number of load balancers provisioned. I would raise the issue with your cluster administrator.

Comment: Turns out the problem was indeed in cluster configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your Service is trying to create a new Load Balancer in AWS and the quota for your region is exceeded. I would assume you have 20 since that is the default:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_elastic_load_balancer

Here are instructions on how to request Limit Increase:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html

Comment: It is not AWS, I'm dealing with local cluster. So I need to know what's wrong with local cluster (if any). Plus it is unclear what the limit should and how it is limited. Basically what the 20 means, number of balancers? How many cluster may have? How many are occupied?

Comment: Service type: LoadBalancer integrates with cloud provides. Try changing it to NodePort. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services---service-types

Comment: That's was the option I considered, but I can't find out if NodePort can serve multiple end-points (routes to different apps). Basically I need a single frontend which redirect /app1 to one backend on one port and /app2 to another backend on another port. I'll be glad to try but I can't find any example how to do it on kubernetes web site.

Comment: Replacing LoadBalancer with NodePort for the Service type will keep everything in the example behind the service the same. It is just going to use an end point (open port on your Node) instead of physical Load Balancer for access to your cluster.